# Android Studio using 100% of disk

Tags: android, react-native, disk-access

I have just installed Android Studio to follow a react native project and everytime I try to use the program the disk usage goes to 100%.
I've chosen Pixel 2 as the phone and android Q and R as the versions.
The program works well until I click the "play" button to start emulating the android OS.
Then the phone image starts loading the android OS but it's just too slow to do anything with the emulated phone.
I have tried reinstalling the program.
I have tried disabling firewall and windows defender.
I have tried using different versions of android ex.: Q and R.

I have 8GB of RAM
HD of 465GB
Intel Core i3-4150 @3.50GHz
GeForce GTX 750 Ti 2gb

I also tried to increase memory size for android studio on file studio.vmoptions.

```
From this
-Xms128m
-Xmx800m
To this
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

I have also created a gradle.properties file with
`org.gradle.daemon=true` as I saw in another question but none of the things above worked.
I have no more clue on what else I could do.

Comment: Did you install HAXM and use x86 image?

Comment: you should have rather focus on Disk-type rather than Graphics while buying laptop. SSD provide a lot of performance on speed rather than Graphics Card.

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator required big memory to launch it and as per your PC configuration so you build an emulator for N and use pixel phone not pixel 2 okay.
hopefully, they resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Usage on Task Manager is not the volume of disk being used.

It is fraction of speed of data transfer from your Disk to RAM.

Usually Hard Disk has lower Read/Write speeds and act as bottleneck for the performance of PC. There is no problem with your Android Studio or any other software. Any Software that requires a lot of Read/Write operations on your Disk will show 100% Disk Usage. You cannot do anything with that.

Unless you replace your computer Hard Disk Drive(HDD) with Solid State Drive(SSD). Because Solid State Drives has very high Read/Write Speed than Hard Disk Drives.

For Now you can use your Android Device for testing rather using an emulator, it will save your computer resources used by emulator.

I know this answer will not help you right now. But this is the correct answer and reality. Go Checkout the Difference between HDD and SSD in Google.